# Save RGB values to jpeg use libjpeg, getting weird results

Tags: c++, image, jpeg, libjpeg

I have a program that will load a jpeg image and allow the user to draw on the image and resave it.

I have loading and drawing working, but when I try to save the image I get this result

[image]

The result should have just been the image of the snail with the line.

Here is my code

```
bool IOManager::save_jpg_to_file(const char *file_name) {
struct jpeg_compress_struct cinfo;

struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;

FILE * outfile;
JSAMPROW row_pointer[1];
int row;

JSAMPLE * image_buffer;

cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);
jpeg_create_compress(&cinfo);

if ((outfile = fopen(file_name_.c_str(), "wb")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s\n", file_name_);
    return false;
}

jpeg_stdio_dest(&cinfo, outfile);

int img_width = pixel_buffer_->width();
int img_height = pixel_buffer_->height();

cinfo.image_width = img_width;
cinfo.image_height = img_height;
cinfo.input_components = 3;
cinfo.in_color_space = JCS_RGB;

jpeg_set_defaults(&cinfo);
jpeg_set_quality(&cinfo, 100, TRUE);

jpeg_start_compress(&cinfo, TRUE);

unsigned char bytes[img_width * 3];

while (cinfo.next_scanline < cinfo.image_height) {
    for (int i = 0;  i < img_width; i+=3){
        ColorData colorData = pixel_buffer_->get_pixel(i, cinfo
                .next_scanline);
        bytes[i] = static_cast<int>(colorData.red()*255) & 0xff;
        bytes[i+1] = static_cast<int>(colorData.green()*255) & 0xff;
        bytes[i+2] = static_cast<int>(colorData.blue()*255) & 0xff;
    }
    row_pointer[0] = bytes;
    (void) jpeg_write_scanlines(&cinfo, row_pointer, 1);
}

jpeg_finish_compress(&cinfo);
fclose(outfile);
jpeg_destroy_compress(&cinfo);

std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;

return true;
}
```

PixelBuffer is just a 2D array of RGB values.

I cannot figure out why it is generating those weird line, any help?

Comment: Are you sure you need to jump every 3 pixels in your pixel_buffer? You probably need to have separately counter there that grows slower (i.e. += 1)

Comment: Awesome that seemed to work!

Comment: It looks like you're starting with a grayscale image and producing a color image. Are you sure your source has 3 components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting my comment as a separate answer. You seem to be accessing your pixel buffer data in a wrong way: you are jumping over 3 pixels in both source and destination buffer, while (given your code fragment) it looks like you need to process **every** pixel of your source. Make sure you increment index only by 1 not 3 when iterating `pixel_buffer_`